# importing transactions in csv format to quickbooks

Tags: csv, import, quickbooks-online

Hwllo,
This is a newbie question. I am seeking to automate data entry of deposits by importing a csv file to our Quickooks online chart of accounts. The csv file will include a deposit total from a credit card processor payout and information on each credit card payment that is a part of that payout. Thus it will include split transactions, and within each split, credits and debits to appropriate accounts, dates, descriptions and memos. The csv file is created from matching payouts from our credit card processor to individual credit card payments (details available but not relevant to resolving the problem).

Is it possible to import such a csv file to Quickbooks online so it populates our Quickbook accounts with the correct data (i.e, amounts, dates, descriptions, memo)? How should the csv file be formatted? The correct chart of accounts is already established in Quickbooks. Note that this does not include data downloaded from our bank. Thanks for any help.

A simplified example of a csv file shown as text is below. This csv file works for importing into gnucash, the open source bookkeeping program. When importing, the Account column is matched to the appropriate account. This format can be modified as needed.

```
Number,Date,Description,Account,Amount,Memo
DEP,7/6/2023,"Payout , deposited on 2023-07-06",bank,48.6,
,,,"cc fee, Dues 2023",1.4,Source: Dues 2023 on 2023-07-03
,,,"dues, Dues 2023",-40,"Ringo , Source: Dues 2023 on 2023-07-03"
,,,"donate, Dues 2023",-10,"Ringo, Source: Dues 2023 on 2023-07-03"
DEP,5/25/2023,"Payout , deposited on 2023-05-25",bank,97.5,
,,,"cc fee, Dues 2023",2.5,Source: Dues 2023 on 2023-05-23
,,,"dues, Dues 2023",-40,"Paul, Source: Dues 2023 on 2023-05-23"
,,,"donate, Dues 2023",-60,"Paul, Source: Dues 2023 on 2023-05-23"
DEP,5/11/2023,"Payout , deposited on 2023-05-11",bank,97.5,
,,,"cc fee, Donations",2.5,Source: Donations on 2023-05-09
,,,"donate, Donations",-100,"George, Source: Donations on 2023-05-09"
```